# How to stop glpk solver after presolve stage and use the result after the presolve stage in Pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, glpk

I want to stop the optimization using glpk solver in Pyomo after very first iterations because after the solution is not getting better and use this value as the result of my model. How is it possible to do that in Pyomo? Setting options as mipgap or tmlim do not help at all. On the screenshot I want to stop my solver right after 1811 and use this value as the result of my objective function.

```
solver = SolverFactory("glpk")
# solver.options["mipgap"] = 100
# solver.options["tmlim"] = 2
results = solver.solve(pyomo_model, options={"seed": PYOMO_SEED}, tee=True)
results.write()
```

[image]

Comment: The highlighted solution is not integer feasible.

Comment: After long-step dual simplex the optimal solution is still 1811. Let's assume that highlighted solution is optimal how it is possible to force the solver to stop after the line OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND? Optimal LP solution is ok for me but I cannot find the option to stop my solver...

Comment: Just remove the integer restrictions in the model. That makes it an LP.

Comment: No, it is not the case. I have two objective functions. For the first one I can remove the integer restrictions and it is ok for but for the second objective function I cannot do that. In pyomo it is modelled in one model with activate and deactivate tricks.

Comment: No, that is nonsense. The highlighted solution is the LP solution.

Comment: You are right but my question is not about that. Let's imagine that I do not want to wait 10000 iteration in long-step dual simplex and if the solution is not found after say 1300 iterations then stop optimization and use LP solution then.

Comment: "*On the screenshot I want to stop my solver right after 1811 and use this value as the result of my objective function.*" This is done by solving the relaxation.,

Comment: After the discussion with you I understood that maybe it is better to reformulate the question. I want using pyomo somehow to stop the optimization after say 1300 iteration but cannot find the way how to do that. But regarding my first question you helped me a lot. Thank you very much. If you know the answer to the second one it would be great.

Comment: AFAIK, glpk is not providing an iteration limit. Use a different solver (almost all LP/MIP have such an option).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try other solvers then.